# how to clearInterval jQuery

Tags: jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Hi I want to use `clearInterval()` to stop a setInterval which is calling from a function by clicking on a link, When i click on link my `setInterval()` `(for 30 seconds)` starts working very well but I want if user click on link again then setInterval() starts again. Please check my code below

**SCRIPT**

```
    function otpTimer(container, count) {
          container.find('timer').html(count + ' seconds');
          setInterval(function () {
            if (count < 1) {
              container.find('.resend').show();
              container.find('.setTimer').hide();
            }
            else {
              count--;
              container.find('.timer').html(count + ' seconds');
            }
          }, 1000);
        }

    function stopOtpTimer(clearme) {
      window.clearInterval(clearme);
    }

$(document).on('click', '.loginContainer #resendForgotPasswordOtpLink', function (e) {

    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    var count = 30;
    var container = $(this).closest('.otpIcon');
    var timer;

    container.find('.resend').show();
    container.find('.setTimer').show();

    stopOtpTimer(timer);
timer = otpTimer(container, count);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement for the value returned by `setInterval` from your `otpTimer` function.

So:

```
return setInterval(....)
```

Comment: thanks for help... please check this http://cssdeck.com/labs/cqfachn9 .. and click on 'HERE' several times then you can see the problem which I am facing

Answer (score 0):

Here from where you are declaring "var timer", replace from there to the end, by the following changes, should give the expected behaviour by you.

```
container.find('.resend').show();
container.find('.setTimer').show();
if(timer){
   stopOtpTimer(timer);
   timer = otpTimer(container, count);
}else{
  var timer;
  timer = otpTimer(container, count);
}
```

Comment: thanks for help... please check this http://cssdeck.com/labs/cqfachn9 .. and click on 'HERE' several times then you can see the problem which I am facing

Answer (score 0):

declare `clearme` publicly before and outside the functions

```
clearme = setInterval(function () {
            if (count < 1) {
              container.find('.resend').show();
              container.find('.setTimer').hide();
            }
            else {
              count--;
              container.find('.timer').html(count + ' seconds');
            }
          }, 1000);
```

and then to clear the interval:

```
clearInterval(clearme);
```

Comment: thanks for help... please check this http://cssdeck.com/labs/cqfachn9 .. and click on 'HERE' several times then you can see the problem which I am facing